# Java: What is "for (;;)"

Tags: java

Would any one please explain this instruction for me:
for (;;)

I have encountered several kinds of these mark (like in ajax code of facebook and in concurrent stuff of Java).

Comment: #define EVER ;;
for(EVER) //...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An infinite loop.

Each of the three parts of a for loop (`for(x; y; z)`) is optional.

So you can do this:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < 20; ++i)
```

and it's perfectly valid, or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20;) { ++i; }
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; ; ++i) { if (i < 20) { break; } }
```

and they're all valid.

You can also omit all three parts, with `for(;;)`. Then you have a loop that:

- does no initialization (the first part)
- has no condition for stopping (the middle part)
- does nothing after each iteration (the last part)

so basically an endless loop. It just does what it says in the loop body, again and again

Comment: See the Java Language Specification §14.14.1.2 http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.1.2 for reference: "If the _Expression_ is not present, or it is present and the value resulting from its evaluation (including any possible unboxing) is `true`, then the contained *Statement* is executed. "

Comment: This answer pretty much proves the awesomeness of the "No question is too simple" policy.  :)

Answer (score 6):

It's an endless loop. For the specificion of the `for` statement, see [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14).

Answer (score 5):

That's an infinite loop, similar to

```
while(true)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its an infinite loop, seeing as the (non-existent) exit condition will never be false.

Any for loop without an exit condition will be infinite:

```
for (int x=0; ; x++) { }
```

Exactly the same as `while (true)`, although a little less readable IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed an infinite loop. But in Java you should really prefer `while (true)` over `for (;;)` since it's more readable (which you probably already realize). The compiler will optimize it anyway. In JavaScript there's no means of a compiler and every byte over HTTP counts, that's the reason why `for (;;)` is preferred.  It saves a few characters (bytes).

Comment: +1 for readability of `while (true)`

Comment: I find `for(;;)` to be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for a for loop is

```
for (init-stmt; condition; next-stmt) {

}
```

So it is simply a for loop with no initial statement, next statement or condition. The absence of the exiting condition makes it infinite.