# strange for loop? C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, interpretation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# is a for(;;) safe and what does it really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893087/in-c-is-a-for-safe-and-what-does-it-really-do)

So i recently came across something ive never seen before..

```
        for (; ; )
        {

        }
```

What is exactly happening when the feilds are left blank like that?

Comment: almost a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401159/for-or-while-true-which-is-the-correct-c-infinite-loop

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an infinite loop.

Somewhere inside there should be a `break;` statement, or possibly an exception thrown in order for control to pass beyond the loop.

You could also achieve the same thing (probably more obviously) by doing

```
while (true)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite loop, almost equivalent to a `while(true)` loop.

The `break` condition is not there in between the two semicolons, therefore, it must be there somewhere in the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

That's an infinite for loop.